# How to implement .NET Core Identity with a custom WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-webapi, identity

I'm having a brainfart moment (read: "a week"). I can't figure out how to implement .Net Core Identity to my web project.

I have WebAPI (.NET Core 3.1) project and Web project (Razor pages). WThe WebAPI project is intended to have all the database communication, Web project should only be used to connect to the WebAPI and display the data.

in the Web project I've scaffolded the Identity and got Register, Login, Logout pages. However, scaffolding creates new DatabaseContext and connects to the database that way.

What I want is to implement it to connect to my WebAPI and call my UserController endpoint.

Can someone please point me in the right direction, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked for me:

I've added a new UserStore. 
Created new class : ApplicationUserStore and implemented interfaces IUserStore, IUserPasswordStore, IUserEmailStore.

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : IUserStore<IdentityUser>, IUserPasswordStore<IdentityUser>, IUserEmailStore<IdentityUser>
{}
```

And in IdentityHostingStartup.cs I've removed the scaffolded context:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationWebContext>();
```

And added my store instead of it:

```
public class IdentityHostingStartup : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {

        builder.ConfigureServices((context, services) => {

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddUserStore<ApplicationUserStore>();

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Database context needs to inherit from the below classes.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;    

public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, int, ApplicationUserClaim, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationRoleClaim, ApplicationUserToken>
        {
            public MyContext (DbContextOptions<MyContext > options)
                : base(options)
            {

            }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your help. But I don't really understand how changes to the context will help? I don't want Web project to have any connection to the database....